# SSRS Report, How do I have Group By on the Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In MS SQL 2008 R2 DB, I have a table:

```
Name, Value, Type
A, 1, T1
B, 2, T1
C, 3, T1
D, 4, T1

A, 10, T2
B, 20, T2
C, 13, T2
D, 45, T2

A, 11, T3
B, 22, T3
C, 33, T3
D, 44, T3
```

What I want to do is to get this:

```
Name, Type
  T1, T2, T3
A, 1, 10, 11
B, 2, 20, 22
C, 3, 13, 33
D, 4, 45, 44
```

From the query, I can return this:
    Name, Value, Type
    A, 1, T1
    B, 2, T1
    C, 3, T1
    D, 4, T1

```
A, 10, T2
B, 20, T2
C, 13, T2
D, 45, T2

A, 11, T3
B, 22, T3
C, 33, T3
D, 44, T3
```

Now I want to take this data and in SSRS, transform it into this form:

```
Name, Type
      T1, T2, T3
    A, 1, 10, 11
    B, 2, 20, 22
    C, 3, 13, 33
    D, 4, 45, 44
```

Types can change from one execution to another.

Comment: More details will help us to provide more details in response: Are you using SQL Server Reporting Services? Have you built a report? Or do you want this done in a SQL query? Where will this be referenced? Are the columns (T1, T2, T3) dynamic from execution to execution or are they fixed? In other words, what have you tried, and what are your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, you have 2 options here:

You can modify your query using PIVOT to transpose the rows into columns

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Or you can simply create a 'Matrix' report. Where `Name` is your Row value, `type` is your column value and `value` is your details value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new report using the Business Intelligence Development Studio "Report Wizard." It will guide you through creating a data set, row groups and column groups.

Once you are familiar with these, then you probably won't want to use the wizard, but for someone getting started with a matrix, it's a good fit.